# Swift, Pass data from popover controller to previous controller

Tags: ios, swift

*i want to fill text View in current controller from data existing in popover controller 
with out reload data in current controller
can i do it ??*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom delegate method to fill the value.

```
class PopupviewController {

    weak var delegate: filleTextViewDelegate?

    func calldelegate () {
       delegate?.fillTextview(filledData)
   }  
}
protocol filleTextViewDelegate : class {
          func fillTextview(filledData: String)
}
class CurrentViewController :filleTextViewDelegate {

   func fillTextview(filledData: String) {
    textView.text = filledData   
   }

}
```