# Swift 2.1 - Using UITableView for a single cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to achieve something similar to the following example image
where I want to present a selected or default category on the first screen
and when it's clicked it moves to the next screen with other category options to choose.

In this example, where it says `Entertainment` and `Project 01` represent different data entities (data store) and it looks like it's using UITableView with each UITableViewCell connected to different data store.
I first want to know if my analysis so far is correct.

In my case, I just need to do that `Entertainment` part and in the next screen, show all category options like the second screen in the example. And after selection is made, the first screen should reflect the selection from the second screen.

Is UITableView the right choice to show this single field (cell) and segue to another ViewController?

All the demo app examples I see, don't demonstrate the usage of UITableView for this purpose so I'm not sure what is the best option in my case.

[image]

Comment: Why not? Everything is just data, u click on the cell, bring to the 2nd, then in 2nd, user choose sth, u call 1st as delegate to do something with that data, u can even change everything in 1st VC, doesnt matter if your tableView just holding 1 cell or many cells

Comment: check below  link how delegate works and all  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242058/swift-pass-data-from-popover-controller-to-previous-controller/35242265#35242265

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes UITableView is a good option. Just create a delegate method in "choose category" class. Call the delegate on didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of the UITableView in Category class. Then assign Expense class as the delegate for the category class.

Basically you'll be performing a segue once you click on entertainment. User will be presented with "Choose Category controller" Once the user selects the table row. Delegate will be called. Implement that delegate in the expense class. And in the implementation just reload the table with the new value.

## UPDATE:

Your choose category class will be something similar to :

```
import UIKit

protocol ChooseCategoryControllerDelegate: class {
func categoryController(controller: ChooseCategoryTableViewController,  didSelectCategory category: String)
}

class ChooseCategoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

 let categories = ["category1","category2","category3","category4"]
var selectedcategory: String!
weak var delegate: ChooseCategoryControllerDelegate!

// MARK: - Table view data source
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return categories.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TypeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

 cell.textLabel?.text = categories[indexPath.row]

 return cell
}

// MARK: - Table view delegate
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
 selectedcategory = categories[indexPath.row] as? String
 delegate.categoryController(self, didSelectCategory: selectedcategory)
}
}
```

In your expense controller add the following code outside your class declaration:

```
extension ExpenseController: ChooseCategoryControllerDelegate {
func typesController(controller: ChooseCategoryTableViewController,  didSelectCategory category: String) {
let selectedCategory = category
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

//update your table category with the new category!!
//reload your table here
}
}
```

Re-Update:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "CategorySegue" {

  let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ChooseCategoryTableViewController

  controller.delegate = self
}
}
```

Also name your segue as "CategorySegue"

Comment: Thank you. I'm a little bit lost what kind of delegate method should be called and assigned to which. Would you mind sharing the code structure?

Comment: I will refer to this structure and keep you posted on how I go, thank you!

Comment: What does this code do? `delegate.categoryController(self, didSelectCategory: selectedcategory)` I guess I will need to use `indexpath.row` to make delegate know what is selected?

Comment: I'm getting nil on the delegate. And it looks like passing data between viewcontrollers with delegate is not quite possible. Would you mind elaborating how I can receive data of selected category with delegate?

Comment: Very sorry I missed something. In didselectrowatindexpath also assign the value to the selectedcategory variable that is passed in the delegate. I'm updating the code!!

Comment: I've implemented your update but I still have error saying delegate is nil. Please see my other question relating to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322178/swift-2-1-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-on-delegate-meth/36322437?noredirect=1#comment60269697_36322437

Comment: Just add the above edited code to your Expense class as well.

Comment: Thanks. My question here would be, if I need to implement `prepareForSegue` what is the purpose of protocol/delegate code? I'm just curious what role delegate plays in this situation as I have `prepareForSegue` in other viewcontroller that works fine without delegate. Thank you, I'm learning something because of you!

Comment: We just need to make the expense controller as the delegate of the chooseCategory controller. Its not mandatory for you to assign the delegate in prepareForSegue only. You can assign it globally also. But its a better approach to assign whenever you require.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if the only option is the Entertainment then maybe UITableView is not the best option. Regardless, you can use a UITableView with static cells and a segue from the entertainment cell to the category.