# Swift 2.1 - Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional on delegate method call

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following two ViewControllers (one is TableViewController) that 
CategoryTableViewController has a delegate method which will be called when Table Cell is selected. Then CreateRecipeViewController implements this delegate method and handles the selected category string.

I'm getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional` at the line `delegate.categoryController(self, didSelectCategory: categoryCell)`

`print(categoryCell)` correctly prints the string value of selected table cell so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

I'm new to implementing protocol so there may be a high chance I'm doing this wrong. I'd much appreciate if some one can give me a clue of this error.

**CategoryTableViewController (choose category)**

```
protocol CategoryTableViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func categoryController(controller: CategoryTableViewController, didSelectCategory category: String)
}

class CategoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    ...

    weak var delegate: CategoryTableViewControllerDelegate!

    ...

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {        

        if let categoryCell = recipeCategory[indexPath.row].name {
            print(categoryCell)
            delegate.categoryController(self, didSelectCategory: categoryCell)
        }
    }

}
```

**CreateRecipeViewController (receives selected category)**

```
extension CreateRecipeViewController: CategoryTableViewControllerDelegate {
    func categoryController(controller: CategoryTableViewController, didSelectCategory category: String) {

        let selectedCategory = category
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        let cell = RecipeCategoryCell()
        cell.configureSelectedCategoryCell(selectedCategory)

        recipeCategoryTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: Would you mind elaborating how I can make delegate hold the value of `categoryCell`. I'm new to this.

Comment: Is downvote really necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to assign a value to the property `delegate`. In other words, `delegate` is nil.

Since `delegate` is an implicitly unwarped optional type, you don't need to add a question mark or an exclamation mark to unwrap it. This is why you didn't see the mistake.

To solve this, just put a question mark after `delegate`:

```
delegate?.categoryController(self, didSelectCategory: categoryCell)
```

But that doesn't solve the problem! This way, `categoryController(:didSelectCategory:)` will never be called!

Unfortunately, I cannot think of a way to pass data between view controllers using delegation. But there is a simpler way to do that.

For simplicity, let's call `CategoryTableViewController` the *sender* and `CreateRecipeViewController` the receiver.

This is what I guess you want to do. You want the user to select a category in the sender and pass the selected category to the receiver. So in the sender, you need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier`, right?

When the view is going to perform a segue, `prepareForSegue` is called. You need to override that method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryBoardSegue) {
    if segue.identifier == "your segue's identifier" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! reciever
        destinationVC.selectedCategory = self.selectedCategory
    }
}
```

There is some stuff that is undefined in the above code. Let's define them now.

The first thing is `destination.selectedCategory`. You add a property in the receiver:

```
var selectedCategory: String!
```

In the `viewDidLoad` of the receiver, you can use this property to know what the user selected. In other words, the data is passed to this property.

The second is `self.selectedCategory`. Let's define that as well, in the sender:

```
var selectedCategory: String!
```

In the `tableView(:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath:)` of sender, you need to assign `self.selectedCategory` the category selected:

```
self.categorySelected = recipeCategory[indexPath.row].name
```

And BOOM! That's it!

Comment: Thanks. I thought the whole purpose of implementing delegate is to share properties between multiple viewcontrollers. I have implemented `prepareForSegue` for receiver -> sender as I have a tableview on receiver, too. Are you saying `prepareForSegue` is necessary for sender -> receiver? and delegate is not needed? Please see the updated image.

Comment: `prepareForSegue` is needed when you need to do something before you go another view controller. I mostly override it when I want to pass a value to another vc. So yes, it is needed for sender -> receiver. The whole point of delegation is _not_ passing data between view controllers. It is used when a class needs to notify another class that something has happened to it. For example, the `UITextFieldDelegate` has methods like `didEndEditing`. That tells the implementing class that the text field has ended editing. It's a bit like callbacks in Javascript. @SeongLee

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the concept of delegate. I will keep posted how I went with your guideline, thanks a lot!

Comment: Additional note: I suppose I can remove all this protocol and delegate in my code as prepareForSegue will satisfy my need. Just for learning purpose and my future reference, would you mind showing me how I can utilise this delegate I currently have? So I know when and where to employ delegate.

Comment: I applied this structure according to the person answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299496/swift-2-1-using-uitableview-for-a-single-cell and he seems to believe there is a way to pass data with delegate. What is your opinion?

Comment: @SeongLee Sorry, but I only use delegates in the framework. I have never created a delegate myself before. But if you want to learn, I recommend you to look at how the `UITextFieldDelegate` is implemented.