# Swift 2.1 - IBOutlet property is nil in custom UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I believe creating a custom class to configure a table cell is a standard practice of iOS development. I apply this practice to my app as well but I'm having some issue with it.

I have two tableviews - one for each `ViewController` - that their cell is using the same custom cell class.

**CustomCellClass**

```
import UIKit

class RecipeCategoryCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var recipeCategoryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var chooseCategoryLabel: UILabel!

    //...

    func configureCell(recipe: Recipe) {
        let category = recipe.category as? RecipeCategory
        recipeCategoryLabel.text = category!.name
    }

    func configureNewCell(category: RecipeCategory) {
        recipeCategoryLabel.text = category.name
    }

    // re-configure receiver's viewcontroller cell with selected category value
    func configureSelectedCategoryCell(selectedCategory: String) {        
        recipeCategoryLabel.text = selectedCategory
    }

    // configure all available category names in the sender's viewcontroller
    func configureChooseCategoryCell(category: RecipeCategory) {
        chooseCategoryLabel.text = category.name
    }
}
```

`@IBOutlet weak var recipeCategoryLabel: UILabel!` belongs to a receiver viewController and `@IBOutlet weak var chooseCategoryLabel: UILabel!` belongs to a sender viewController

I have an issue at the 3rd function at this line `recipeCategoryLabel.text = selectedCategory` that `Xcode` says

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value

I don't have this issue on other functions that uses the same IBOutlet `recipeCategoryLabel` but only the function `configureSelectedCategoryCell()` that re-configures receiver ViewController cell with selected category value.
So I can say for certainty that this is not a connection problem with storyboard.

I suppose this is happening because the same IBOutlet property is used in multiple places. But the thing is that, I have to use the same property so I can set default value, update the selected value, set previously persisted value on the same label.

I don't know if my explanation is clear enough but basically I cannot set the table cell label of receiver's `ViewController` with the selected category value that was passed from the sender's `ViewController`.

**UPDATE**

[image]

And `configureSelectedCategoryCell()` is called in the receiver's ViewController extension:

```
extension CreateRecipeVC: RecipeCategoryTableVCDelegate {

func categoryController(controller: RecipeCategoryTableVC, didSelectCategory category: String) {

    selectedCategory = category

    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    let cell = RecipeCategoryCell()
    cell.configureSelectedCategoryCell(selectedCategory)

}
```

}

Comment: are you sure you selectedCategory is not a nil object?

Comment: Is it possible that you are calling this function before the component has been loaded and connected to the IBOutlet?

Comment: When are you calling `configureSelectedCategoryCell` and with which mechanisms (NSNotification, direct call, etc)?

Comment: Please see update image. It prints selectedCategory with correct string where it says "Drink" in the console.

Comment: @Manuel The function is called in receiver's ViewController extension. See my update.

Comment: Can you post the ViewController's code related to cell dequeuing and displaying?

Comment: This looks fishy: let cell = RecipeCategoryCell(). Why aren't you calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier? See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell's outlets are not instantiated at the point when you try to access them in `configureSelectedCategoryCell`.

As I understand the cells are designed in Interface Builder, so the outlets of the cell object `cell` are missing the references to the controls in Interface Builder.

After a category is selected you should

1. Update the tableView's data source
2. Reload the tableView's items

Something like this:

```
func categoryController(controller: RecipeCategoryTableVC, didSelectCategory category: String) {

    selectedCategory = category
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    tableViewDataSource[selectedItemIndex].selectedCategory = selectedCategory
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Then in the table view data source delegate:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCellIdentifer") as! RecipeCategoryCell
   cell.configureSelectedCategoryCell(tableViewDataSource[indexPath.row].selectedCategory)
   return cell
}
```

**Side notes:**

It is legit to connect one IBOutlet to multiple controls in the storyboard.

As precaution I suggest to remove the force unwrapping of an optional in `configureCell`, e.g.

```
func configureCell(recipe: Recipe) {
    if let category = recipe.category as? RecipeCategory {
       recipeCategoryLabel.text = category.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't quite get the datasource update part `tableViewDataSource[selectedItemIndex].selectedCategory = selectedCategory` I can get the index of selected item from the sender but not sure why this assignment is necessary when I already know what selectedCategory holds.

Comment: Can you describe the logic of your app concerning the two table view? I understood that one table view is for selecting a recipe category. What is the other table view for and which of the two table views causes the exception?

Comment: This is my previous question which explains the logic behind two table views. The exception is thrown at the receiver - CreateRecipeViewController
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322178/swift-2-1-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-on-delegate-meth

Comment: @SeongLee Thank you.  Is the table view in CreateRecipeVC static or dynamic, i.e. do you provide a data source in CreateRecipeVC or did you design the cells fixed in Interface Builder?

Comment: Although I only have one cell, I'm using dynamic cell in CreateRecipeVC as there will be various cases in presenting this single cell. By the way, I got this working following your guideline! `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCellIdentifer")` was the key. I will update my question to show what I did with the data.

Comment: See my updated working code in the question. Thank you!